# How to perform functions that reference previous row on subset of data in a dataframe using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have some log data that represents an item (id) and a timestamp that an action was a started and I want to determine the time between actions on each item.

for example, I have some data that looks like this:

```
data = [{"timestamp":"2019-05-21T14:17:29.265Z","id":"ff9dad92-e7c1-47a5-93a7-6e49533a6e25"},{"timestamp":"2019-05-21T14:21:49.722Z","id":"ff9dad92-e7c1-47a5-93a7-6e49533a6e25"},{"timestamp":"2019-05-21T15:16:25.695Z","id":"ff9dad92-e7c1-47a5-93a7-6e49533a6e25"},{"timestamp":"2019-05-21T15:16:25.696Z","id":"ff9dad92-e7c1-47a5-93a7-6e49533a6e25"},{"timestamp":"2019-05-22T07:51:17.49Z","id":"ff12891e-5786-438b-891c-abd4244723b4"},{"timestamp":"2019-05-22T08:11:13.948Z","id":"ff12891e-5786-438b-891c-abd4244723b4"},{"timestamp":"2019-05-22T11:52:59.897Z","id":"ff12891e-5786-438b-891c-abd4244723b4"},{"timestamp":"2019-05-22T11:53:03.406Z","id":"ff12891e-5786-438b-891c-abd4244723b4"},{"timestamp":"2019-05-22T11:53:03.481Z","id":"ff12891e-5786-438b-891c-abd4244723b4"},{"timestamp":"2019-05-21T14:23:08.147Z","id":"fe55bb22-fe5b-4b12-8aaf-d5f0320ac7fa"},{"timestamp":"2019-05-21T14:29:18.228Z","id":"fe55bb22-fe5b-4b12-8aaf-d5f0320ac7fa"},{"timestamp":"2019-05-21T15:17:09.831Z","id":"fe55bb22-fe5b-4b12-8aaf-d5f0320ac7fa"},{"timestamp":"2019-05-21T15:17:09.834Z","id":"fe55bb22-fe5b-4b12-8aaf-d5f0320ac7fa"},{"timestamp":"2019-05-21T14:02:19.072Z","id":"fd3554cd-b83d-49af-a8e6-7bf41c741cd0"},{"timestamp":"2019-05-21T14:02:34.867Z","id":"fd3554cd-b83d-49af-a8e6-7bf41c741cd0"},{"timestamp":"2019-05-21T14:12:28.877Z","id":"fd3554cd-b83d-49af-a8e6-7bf41c741cd0"},{"timestamp":"2019-05-21T15:19:19.567Z","id":"fd3554cd-b83d-49af-a8e6-7bf41c741cd0"},{"timestamp":"2019-05-21T15:19:19.582Z","id":"fd3554cd-b83d-49af-a8e6-7bf41c741cd0"},{"timestamp":"2019-05-21T09:58:02.185Z","id":"f89c2e3e-06dc-467b-813b-dc92f2692f63"},{"timestamp":"2019-05-21T10:07:24.044Z","id":"f89c2e3e-06dc-467b-813b-dc92f2692f63"}]
stack = pd.DataFrame(data)
stack.head()
```

[image]

I have tried getting all the unique ids to split the data frame and then getting the time taken with the index to recombine with the original set like, but the function is extremely slow on large data-sets and messes up both the index 
 and timestamp order resulting in results getting miss matched.

```
import ciso8601 as time
records = []
for i in list(stack.id.unique()):
    dff = stack[stack.id == i]
    time_taken = []
    times = []
    i = 0
    for _, row in dff.iterrows():
        if bool(times):
            print(_)
            current_time = time.parse_datetime(row.timestamp)
            prev_time = times[i]
            time_taken = current_time - prev_time
            times.append(current_time)
            i+=1
            records.append(dict(index = _, time_taken = time_taken.seconds))
        else:
            records.append(dict(index = _, time_taken = 0))
            times.append(time.parse_datetime(row.timestamp))

x = pd.DataFrame(records).set_index('index')
stack.merge(x, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner')
```

[image]

Is there a neat pandas groupby and apply way of doing this so that I don't have to split the frame and store it in memory so that can reference the previous row in the subset?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html):

```
stack['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(stack['timestamp'])
stack['timestamp']= (stack.sort_values(['id','timestamp'])
                            .groupby('id')
                            .diff()['timestamp']
                            .dt.total_seconds()
                            .round().fillna(0))

print(stack['time_taken'])
0         0.0
1       260.0
2      3276.0
3         0.0
4         0.0
5      1196.0
6     13306.0
7         4.0
8         0.0
9         0.0
10      370.0
11     2872.0
...
```

---

If you want the resulting dataframe to be ordered by date, instead do:

```
stack['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(stack['timestamp']) 
stack = stack.sort_values(['id','timestamp'])
stack['time_taken'] = (stack.groupby('id')
                            .diff()['timestamp'] 
                            .dt.total_seconds() 
                            .round()
                            .fillna(0))
```

Comment: Hmm I think it should be the same but in my case the final df is not ordered. But yes I guess having an ordered result would be more desireable @jez. But also it would not match the expected output

Answer (score 1):

If dont need replace timestamp to datetimes create Series filled by datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and pass to [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html), then convert to seconds by [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html), if necessary round by [`Series.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html) and replace missing values by `0`:

```
t = pd.to_datetime(stack['timestamp'])
stack['time_taken'] = t.groupby(stack['id']).diff().dt.total_seconds().round().fillna(0)

print (stack)
                                      id                 timestamp  time_taken
0   ff9dad92-e7c1-47a5-93a7-6e49533a6e25  2019-05-21T14:17:29.265Z         0.0
1   ff9dad92-e7c1-47a5-93a7-6e49533a6e25  2019-05-21T14:21:49.722Z       260.0
2   ff9dad92-e7c1-47a5-93a7-6e49533a6e25  2019-05-21T15:16:25.695Z      3276.0
3   ff9dad92-e7c1-47a5-93a7-6e49533a6e25  2019-05-21T15:16:25.696Z         0.0
4   ff12891e-5786-438b-891c-abd4244723b4   2019-05-22T07:51:17.49Z         0.0
5   ff12891e-5786-438b-891c-abd4244723b4  2019-05-22T08:11:13.948Z      1196.0
6   ff12891e-5786-438b-891c-abd4244723b4  2019-05-22T11:52:59.897Z     13306.0
7   ff12891e-5786-438b-891c-abd4244723b4  2019-05-22T11:53:03.406Z         4.0
8   ff12891e-5786-438b-891c-abd4244723b4  2019-05-22T11:53:03.481Z         0.0
9   fe55bb22-fe5b-4b12-8aaf-d5f0320ac7fa  2019-05-21T14:23:08.147Z         0.0
10  fe55bb22-fe5b-4b12-8aaf-d5f0320ac7fa  2019-05-21T14:29:18.228Z       370.0
11  fe55bb22-fe5b-4b12-8aaf-d5f0320ac7fa  2019-05-21T15:17:09.831Z      2872.0
12  fe55bb22-fe5b-4b12-8aaf-d5f0320ac7fa  2019-05-21T15:17:09.834Z         0.0
13  fd3554cd-b83d-49af-a8e6-7bf41c741cd0  2019-05-21T14:02:19.072Z         0.0
14  fd3554cd-b83d-49af-a8e6-7bf41c741cd0  2019-05-21T14:02:34.867Z        16.0
15  fd3554cd-b83d-49af-a8e6-7bf41c741cd0  2019-05-21T14:12:28.877Z       594.0
16  fd3554cd-b83d-49af-a8e6-7bf41c741cd0  2019-05-21T15:19:19.567Z      4011.0
17  fd3554cd-b83d-49af-a8e6-7bf41c741cd0  2019-05-21T15:19:19.582Z         0.0
18  f89c2e3e-06dc-467b-813b-dc92f2692f63  2019-05-21T09:58:02.185Z         0.0
19  f89c2e3e-06dc-467b-813b-dc92f2692f63  2019-05-21T10:07:24.044Z       562.0
```

Or if need replace timestamp to datetimes use @yatu answer.

Comment: Will the result of the groupby naturally order by timestamp?

Comment: These answers assume the datetimes are ordered

Comment: Check the update in my answer @JohnyMudly . You first have to sort values if order is not guaranteed